# Dojo RequireJS 404 error handling from thirdparty URL

Tags: javascript, requirejs, dojo

I have a dojo require as

```
window.config= {
  async: false,
  paths: {
    'thirdParty' : 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/thirdPartyJSSrc'
  }
};
```

In Page Javascript I am using thirdParty as

```
require([
'thirdParty'
], function(){ });
```

Now if my thirdPartyJSSrc returns 404 the other buttons handlers from JS is not working..It is showing the following error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
Error {src: "dojoLoader", info: Array[2], stack: (...), message: "scriptError"}
```

Because of this error no JS is working on other elements of page..

I don't want to include the JS if particular JS returns 404 on the page..Anyway to do this?

Comment: Look in your dev tools' network tab.  What URL is it attempting to access, vs. what are you expecting it to access?  Also, you might try using packages rather than paths, e.g. `packages: [ { name: 'thirdParty', location: 'https://...' } ]`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest config your dojo with dojoConfig, see documentation [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/dojo_config/).

e.g

```
dojoConfig = {
            baseUrl: "js/",
            packages:[
                { name:"dojo",location:"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dojo/"},
                { name:"dijit", location:"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/"},
                { name:"dojox", location:"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dojox/"},
                { name:"thirdParty",location:"https://s3.amazonaws.com/thirdPartyJSSrc"}],
            parseOnLoad : true,
            async : false,
            isDebug: true,
            locale: 'en'
};
```

I should you to use "dojo/has" for test if exist your "thirdParty" JS. The dojo/has module is Dojo’s feature-detection API. It provides a simple, consistent, and easily extensible approach for evaluating existing feature tests, and for creating your own custom feature tests. dojo/has also implements the AMD loader plugin API, which allows you to use it to conditionally load modules. See "[Dojo FAQ: How can I conditionally load AMD modules?](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2014/02/25/dojo-faq-how-can-i-conditionally-load-amd-modules/)" for more detail.

Comment: Can you please give me example of handling this usecase through dojo.has I tried with require(["dojo/has!feature?package/module:package/other"], function(featureModule){});But I don't want to add other package instead of actual one..I have to check single package